# How to get data from mysql databse using java web services?

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap

I trying to get data from mysql database and store in the Arraylist using java web service *SOAP REQUEST*. But My method return output is like this ***java.util.List : "[chat.in.server.com.ThreadsClass@17b91ad3***

ThreadClass is the class that handle Thread Information. Thread means Messages

How do I get real String data?
[image]

### Thread Class

```
public class ThreadsClass  {

private int id;
private String title;
private String author;
private String date;


public ThreadsClass() {
}

public ThreadsClass(int id,String title, String author, String date) {
    this.id=id;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

### Java web Services Class

```
@WebService(serviceName = "ChatHandle")

public class ChatHandle {

private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;
private ResultSet resultsSet;
private PreparedStatement prepStat;

@WebMethod(operationName = "displayThread")
public ArrayList<ThreadsClass> displayThread() {
       ArrayList<ThreadsClass> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chatapp", "root", "");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultsSet = statement.executeQuery("select id,title, date, author from chatnew");
        while (resultsSet.next()) {
            ThreadsClass t = new ThreadsClass(
            resultsSet.getInt("id"),
            resultsSet.getString("title"),
            resultsSet.getString("author"),
            resultsSet.getString("date"));
            threads.add(t);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
    }
    return threads;
}
}
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could handle the exception and at least print the stacktrace. Without it, we're as blind as you about what may be the issue.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sir I did not get any error. I put code to catch stack trace. But i do not know is it the right way to catch stack trace.

Comment: } catch (Exception e) {
            
           e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
        }

Comment: *sir I did not get any error* you don't know because you have `catch (Exception e) { /* nothing is done here */ }`. You should at least have `e.printStacktrace(System.out);` there to know if you **really** have an exception.

Comment: I did sir. but no exception. @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: From the new info you provided, there's no issue in your service. Looks like you want/need to see the string representation of your object. Currently, you're seeing the call of `toString()` of your list. This is for testing purposes only, so override `toString()` method in your `ThreadsClass` class (I think it should be renamed tho).

Answer (score 0):

Java prints instance hash codes as the default behavior for converting objects to strings. Try implementing `toString()` in your ThreadsClass class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "ThreadsClass: title = " + title + " author = " + author + " date = " + date + " id = " + id;
}
```